# Using sizeof Correctly with Byte[]

Tags: objective-c

I'm sort of out of my depths here, but I have the following code (the real code actually has a point of course):

```
- (NSData*) dataTheseBytes:(Byte[]) bytes {
     return [NSData dataWithBytes:bytes length:sizeof(bytes)];
}
```

The compiler warning is

> Sizeof on array function parameter will return size of 'Byte *' (aka
>   'unsigned char *') instead of 'Byte []'

How can I eliminate this warning (or rather, what am I not understanding about my array of bytes)?

Additionally, why doesn't the error happen with this code? Must have something to do with the method signature...?

```
    Byte bytes[3] = { byte1, byte2, byte3 };
    NSData *retVal = [NSData dataWithBytes:bytes length:sizeof(bytes)];
```

Comment: You're returning the size of your pointer to memory instead of the memory itself.  You probably need to do something like `sizeof(*bytes)`

Comment: Try to use strlen(bytes)

Comment: @mydogisbox, is that right, or is strlen right? Also, could you put this as an answer, please?

Comment: Don't use strlen, use length as specified below.

Comment: @ugho: That question was closed already as a double-post of this. It seems there was a system hiccup when Yar posted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you pass a C array as a method or C function argument, it "decays" to a pointer to the underlying type (i.e. `Byte[]` is actually passed as `Byte *`.) So the called method/function has no idea how many elements are present in the array.

You must also pass the length of the array in order for the called code to know what you want. That's why `+[NSData dataWithBytes:length:]` has that second argument.

Comment: Grynspan, thanks for your answer, but unfortunately the wrong question got marked as a duplicate. Could you please put this answer on the other "duplicate" question?

Comment: @Yar: you could flag for a mod to merge, especially since this is a mistaken double-post.

Comment: Not 100% sure of etiquette here, as my answer has been upvoted on both questions. Delete or not delete?

Comment: @Jonathan Grynspan, please delete the other answer, I've removed my upvote and marked this one as best answer instead. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 2):

c arrays do not embed their element count.

this is how you would declare a method with an unspecified element count. this is not generally usable:

```
`- (NSData*) dataTheseBytes:(const Byte*)bytes;`
// or
`- (NSData*) dataTheseBytes:(const Byte[])bytes;`
```

a more rigid implementation could specify the element count. this is ok if you are always using the same size. example:

```
enum { MONByteBufferElementCount = 23 };
...
`- (NSData*) dataTheseBytes:(const Byte[MONByteBufferElementCount])bytes
{
  return [NSData dataWithBytes:&bytes[0] length:MONByteBufferElementCount * sizeof(bytes[0])];
}
```

the problem with using objc messaging in this case is that the compiler may not be able to determine the appropriate selector and produce an error or warning if you have declared a selector with the same name but uses different parameters or element counts. therefore, it's safer to use a c function:

```
`NSData* DataTheseBytes(const Byte bytes[MONByteBufferElementCount]) {
  return [NSData dataWithBytes:&bytes[0] length:MONByteBufferElementCount * sizeof(bytes[0])];
}
```

or use a more verbose name:

```
`- (NSData*) dataWithMONByteBuffer:(const Byte[MONByteBufferElementCount])bytes
{
  return [NSData dataWithBytes:&bytes[0] length:MONByteBufferElementCount * sizeof(bytes[0])];
}
```

in objc, it's most common to pass the length as an argument, similar to the `NSData` constructor you call. some part of your program will be able to determine this value (whether it is `NSData`, a c array or something else).

```
- (NSData*) dataTheseBytes:(const Byte*)bytes length:(NSUInteger)length
{
  return [NSData dataWithBytes:bytes length:length];
}
```

it's also common to see the element count, like so:

```
- (NSData*) dataTheseFloats:(const float*)floats length:(NSUInteger)count
{
  return [NSData dataWithBytes:floats length:count * sizeof(float)];
}
```

finally, there are of course a few corner cases. the obvious being a null terminated string:

```
- (NSData*) dataWithASCIIString:(const char*)chars
{
  return [NSData dataWithBytes:chars length:strlen(chars)];
}
```

Comment: just to confirm, there is no way to find out the length from the array itself?

Comment: That is correct. Basic C arrays do not have a length property.

Comment: @Yar that is correct with one exception: an array with a fixed element count. answer rewritten to demonstrate the options available to you when using c arrays. another option would be to create a simple struct like `typedef struct t_mon_byte_buffer { Byte* at; size_t count; } t_mon_byte_buffer;`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass arrays to a function. You're passing a pointer to the first element in the array of the caller.

If you need the length of that array, you need to pass that length as a separate argument to your function, and use that instead of `sizeof`